# slice hash in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes like:

```
[{"name"=>"John Doe", "id"=>"1"}, {"name"=>"Jane Doe", "id"=>"2"}]
```

I would like to get back an array of id only. What would be efficient way to do so? I would prefer to avoid using a loop.

Thank you.

Comment: @apneadiving that's why the comment is gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
your_array.map {|h| h["id"]}
```

But basically there is a loop in desguise.

Sidenote:

Imagine there is no `id` in one of the hashes, then you'd have a `nil`. Append `compact` to solve this

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
your_array.pluck(:id)
```

This is faster than `map (loop)`

Same use `compact` to remove `nil`

Comment: _This is faster than map (loop)_, do you happen to have a benchmark?